# Fastest way to flatten nested pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-complexity, pandas-groupby

I am working with a 1,000,000+ row pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

```
DEPARTMENT     ACTION      TASK_CODE      TIME_DURATION
A              CLEAN       0001           25.0
B              REWORK      0002           20.0
C              SCRAP       0003           21.0
D              FIX         0004           22.0
E              DESTROY     0005           24.0
```

My goal is to calculate the average TIME_DURATION of each per DEPARTMENT per ACTION per TASK_CODE. What I've done is as follows:

```
for dep, df1 in df.groupby("DEPARTMENT"):
    for act, df2 in df1.groupby("ACTION"):
        for code, df3 in df2.groupby("TASK_CODE"):
            average_duration = df3["TIME_DURATION"].mean()
```

This isn't a great solution due to a complexity of O(n3). This takes some time with the size of dataframe I have. What is the fastest way possible to go about performing the aforementioned task?

PS. I tried `for x, df1 in df.groupby(["DEPARTMENT", "ACTION", "TASK_CODE"]):`
This operation took a significantly longer time than the first. Also, if the question title doesn't make sense, please suggest edits.

Comment: So `df.groupby(["DEPARTMENT", "ACTION", "TASK_CODE"])["TIME_DURATION"].mean()` is slow ?

Comment: Yes, it took a lot of time. I don't understand why that would be the case.

Comment: why do you need for loop in the first place? like @jezrael said, you can just do `df.groupby(["DEPARTMENT", "ACTION", "TASK_CODE"])["TIME_DURATION"].mean()`